# Attempt to resize (expand) a virtual disk in macOS Mojave not working - VM is hosted in VMware vSphere (similar to Fusion)

Tags: disk-utility, mojave, storage, virtualization, vmware

I'm attempting to expand a vDisk in macOS Mojave, but it's not working. The VM is hosted in VMware vSphere (similar to macOS Fusion on an Intel Mac).

I'm following this VMware KB article

- https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/83098

However, the instructions do not work for reason. I cannot slide the node to the left, it's stuck in the middle:

[image: macOS Mojave - cannot expand vDisk]

I also rebooted to Recovery Mode, but there was no change.

**Update:** I am reading that this issue is due to the disk being formatted as [Apple File System (APFS).](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-dsku19ed921c/mac) Apparently the older "mac OS Journaled" file systems do not have this issue.

Comment: With Fusion I have had success by booting to a specially prepared recovery disk. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YMc1HvamDnWg6wVLibX2RQw13kjCxbYu You might also try https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-E6C50392-31BA-4466-9A2E-D133B48C0E8A.html  You would need to add any such virtual disk to your vSphere vm.

Comment: Thank you! I will try these options :)

Comment: Instead of expanding the original disk I just added a new (larger) VMDK -> formatted it as macOS Journaled -> cloned original disk to new via Carbon Copy Cloner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better answer - expand the disk in vSphere / Fusion / (hypervisor of your choice) normally, then boot and run this command:

- `diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expanding the original disk I just **added a new (larger) VMDK -> formatted it as macOS Journaled -> cloned original disk to new via Carbon Copy Cloner -> shutdown VM and removed the original disk, using the new VMDK as the boot disk.**

I may try expanding later since I am now using the older "macOS Journaled" file system, but my issue is resolved for now.

Comment: This issue is due to the disk being formatted as Apple File System (APFS). I just confirmed I am able to resize the disk now that it's using macOS Journaled.